# How to turn a frequency domain graph to time domain graph

Tags: signal-processing, fft

I wanted to convert the graph in the top red box for the frequency domain to the graph in the bottom red box for the time domain. What should I do?

[image]

Comment: There are multiple issues with this, all of them physics and math, none programming related, but that is often the case with fft questions, so not problem with that since we are talking `numpy.fft`. The bottom is a single pulse (not the full train) in electric field. The top is a power spectrum (abs. value squared) so you can't reproduce the phase of the electric field. Also it is just the envelope of the mode spectrum.  The full picture emerges if you make a pulse train (on the bottom), in electric field, then transform it (gives you full mode spectrum, which you can take the power of).

Comment: For the physics see e.g. Picaso, a method that recovers the electric field (what you want) from the intensity spectrum and nonlinear autocorrelation measurement.

Comment: There is another simple reason why the spectral envelope can't give you the pulse, i.e. it could be a lamp. You could make the argument that it gives you the coherence length which is a lower limit for your pulse length. If the pulse is 'bandwidth limited' (i.e. uses all the bandwidth , or mode locks all modes) then the two are equal.

Comment: Also note that the linear autocorrelation is nothing but the FT of the intensity spectrum, so it doesn't add to the information you need for the pulse shape and phase recovery. You could use it as an alternative for the intensity spectrum, to check the spectrum or to lower noise.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using python, you can use the `scipy` library `irfft` function as explained [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.irfft.html) to get back the time domain signal.

Example:

```
from scipy.fftpack import fft,irfft,rfft

data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

fft = rfft(data)
print("FFT : " , fft)

original_data = irfft(fft)
print("Original : " , original_data)
```

Output :

```
FFT :  [15.   -3.    5.2  -3.    1.73 -3.  ]
Original :  [0. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5.]
```